# conditional sed multiple replacement

Tags: bash, sed

I m trying to create a bash (or sh) script which ask one or more input with `read`, then, generate a config file from a default file and replace the customized default value when they exists with `sed`.

This can be done by multiple call `sed -i` but I wonder if this can be achieved with one command, with something like below.

Do you know if this is possible, and how I can do it ? Or this doesn't worth to do that way and it's better to call multiple times `sed -i` ?

```
echo "config install title? "
read title
if [ -z "$title" ]; then
    echo "title from config-sample.yml will be used to generate config.local.yml."
    #exit 1
fi

echo "config install url (required, start with http:// or https:// )? "
read url
if [ -z "$url" ]; then
    echo "url localhost will be used to generate config.local.yml."
    #exit 1
fi

sed \
    [ -n "$title" ] && -e "s/title:.*/title: \"${title}\" /" \
    [ -n "$url" ]   && -e "s/url:.*/url: \"${url}\" /" \
    config-sample.yml > config.yml
```

an example of config-sample.yml would be:

```
install
  title: "My Project"
  url:   "http://localhost"
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] based on your "this can be done by ...".

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu gettext available, I'd suggest using [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) instead, here's an example:

```
while : ; do
    [[ -z $title ]] && read -rp "config install title? " title
    # keep asking for the title until the user gives it
    [[ -z $title ]] && continue
    read -rp "config install url? " url
    case "$url" in
        # keep asking for the url
        "" )
            continue
            ;;
        # accept urls without protocol and use https by default
        [!http]*)
            url="https://${url}"
            ;;
    esac
    break
done
# export the vars you want to substitute in the template
export title url
envsubst '${title} ${url}' < "config-sample.yml" > "config.yml"
```

The main thing being that you export the wanted vars `$title` `$url` and then give them as options to `envsubst` and it'll replace any occurrence of `${title}`, `$title`, `${url}` and/or `$url` in your `config-sample.yml` and then the output is redirected to the new file `config.yml`